# Python "list index out of range" when I am converting a csv to docx

Tags: python, csv, docx

My csv have blank rows in every 17 rows (blank row in row 17,34....)
I tried to convert it to a docx. However, the "list index out of range" error came out. If I delete the blank row in the csv, it will be working fine. Even if I manually add it via excel and the docx function will be work fine.
It seems that the table.row cannot deal with the blank row in my csv.

```
    row_cells[i].text = row[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Would you please help me? Thank you in advance.

```
path = os.getcwd()
##Use glob.glob to get all the "txt.csv.csv" files.
allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt.csv.csv")
df_out_filename = 'Xunjian-Report.csv'
with open(df_out_filename, 'w+', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for filename in allfiles:
        with open(filename) as fin:
            reader = csv.reader(fin)
            writer.writerows(reader)
            writer.writerow("[]")  ##Insert blank row at the end

###To generate the docx
csvfile = 'Xunjian-Report.csv'
doc = docx.Document()
date = datetime.datetime.now()
with open(csvfile, newline='') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    csv_headers = next(csv_reader)
    csv_cols = len(csv_headers)
    print(csv_cols)
    # Adding Subject of the document and the date
    doc.add_heading('Report', level=0)
    doc.add_heading('Date: %s/%s/%s' % (date.day, date.month, date.year), level=1)
    table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=csv_cols)
    table.autofix=False
    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    for i in range(csv_cols):
        hdr_cells[i].text = csv_headers[i]
    for row in csv_reader:
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        for i in range(csv_cols):
            row_cells[i].text = row[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `row` list does not have enough elements for `row[i]`, you hit `IndexError`. If you have blank rows in your input, those will indeed be shorter (or even just empty list).

Depending on your processing needs you could, either only process as many columns as you have in each row, replace:

```
for i in range(csv_cols):
```

with:

```
for i in range(len(row)):
```

Or even:

```
for (idx, cell) in enumerate(csv_cols):
    row_cells[idx].text = cell
```

Or skip rows that are empty list (but this is a bit less robust, former would also deal with uneven length of rows, should it be possible to hit that case):

```
for row in csv_reader:
```

Could read:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    if not row: continue  # skip empty row, go to the next one
```